# Parsing JSON with key-value-value (django/python)

Tags: python, json, django

I am making an RSVP form where the invitee can opt to bring a guest (or 2 or 3). The form has inputs generated x number of times, where x is the # of guests the user sets. So for example, if the user chooses "0" from the dropdown, they're not bringing a guest so the form only has inputs for 1 person (themselves). If they select "1" from the dropdown, the form duplicates all the fields, but there is still just one route/one submit button. The duplicated form fields are identical to the original, so the form has 2 inputs named "name", 2 inputs named "dinner", etc.

I get a dictionary when I print request.POST:

```
<QueryDict: {u'restrictions': [u'None', u'Gluten'], u'name': [u'Krista', u'Joel'], u'dinner': [u'chicken', u'fish'], u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'iEjxo6KgLGHZWwvaxEd6I7CUd7GTs89VGpiKwmiCP9xqXKFK096s0vboK4pPQxea']}>
```

In vanilla python I can access the values like so:

```
dictionary['restrictions'][1]
```

which returns "Gluten".  But in Django this expression returns 'e' - the letter at index 1 of the key name 'restrictions'. Likewise,

```
for key, val1, val2 
   print key, val1, val2
```

returns "too many values to unpack", presumably because it's unpacking the letters in the key name instead of the values.

How can I access the values? Alternatively, is there a better way to generate multiple forms based on the user's selection, with just one route and one submit button?

Comment: What's the output of `request.POST['restrictions']`? It should be a list, but it looks like it's a string for some reason. How are you accessing the dictionary, `request.POST['restrictions'][1]`?

Comment: @J.McBride the output of request.POST['restrictions'] is "Gluten", and request.POST['name'] is "Joel". So it's only returning the most recent value for each key.  Yes, request.POST['restrictions'][0] returns 'r' and [1] returns 'e' - so it's returning the letter at those indexes for the word ['restrictions']

Answer (score 2):

You should try `request.POST.getlist('restrictions')`